# python Taking screenshot on test failure in tearDown() method

Tags: python, automated-tests, screenshot, teardown

I'm trying to take a screenshot at the end of a failed test

I've done something that works, but there's a problem:
It takes screenshot of every test that happens after one that failed - for example:
1. Test passed: no screenshot
2. Test failed: screenshot
3. Test passed: screenshot
- so after the first error all tests get a screenshot

I know thats an issue with _resultForDoCleanups method, which in my case can't be replaced with _outcomeForDoCleanups.success, because i'm using python 2.7, not 3.

My code:

```
    def tearDown(self):
            if self._test_has_failed():
                if not os.path.exists(SCREEN_DUMP_LOCATION):
                    os.makedirs(SCREEN_DUMP_LOCATION)
                for ix, handle in enumerate(self.driver.window_handles):
                    self._windowid = ix
                    self.driver.switch_to.window(handle)
                    self.take_screenshot()
            self.driver.quit()

def _test_has_failed(self):
        for method, error in self._resultForDoCleanups.errors:
            if error:
                return True
        return False

def _get_filename(self):
    timestamp = datetime.now().isoformat().replace(':', '.')[:19]
    return "{folder}/{classname}.{method}-window{windowid}-{timestamp}".format(
        folder=SCREEN_DUMP_LOCATION,
        classname=self.__class__.__name__,
        method=self._testMethodName,
        windowid=self._windowid,
        timestamp=timestamp
    )

def take_screenshot(self):
    filename = self._get_filename() + ".png"
    print "\n{method} SCREENSHOT AND HTML:\n".format(
        method=self._testMethodName)
    print 'screenshot:', filename
    self.driver.get_screenshot_as_file(filename)
```

Comment: So you want to check that there's an `error` only for the `method` you *just* tested? A slightly hacky way would be to see if there are more errors than last time you called it.

Comment: yes, for a test case in unittest class

Comment: Why not `logging`? Screenshots are expensive in storage and nearly useless to someone doing postmortem debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is really close to what you want to have happen.

This code is using the comment of @jonrsharpe

```
def tally(self):
    return len(self._resultForDoCleanups.errors) + len(self._resultForDoCleanups.failures)

def setUp(self):
    self.errors_and_failures = self.tally()

def tearDown(self):
    if self.tally() > self.errors_and_failures:
        # Take a screenshot
```

At the start of each test method we find out how many errors and failures we have. When we get to the tearDown method our test method has executed and we will know if there was an error. The tally method will be 1 higher than the self.errors_and_failures variable that we set before the test method.

Hopefully this is what you were looking for.

Comment: @jedrekcienicki On stackexchange you should avoid 'Thank you' comments but you can mark the answer as correct :)